Can one add human-written rules to a Keras model?
For example, there's a set of balls that change colours over time, and every ball has its own colour sequence like "2 seconds of red, 4 seconds of purple, 2 seconds of red, 3 seconds of yellow".
The dataset given to the RNN model has, for instance, 500 rows, and the purpose of the work is to predict the palette for steps 501-750.
The columns of the dataframe are:

step/time measured in seconds
black (100 at the zero step)
red
orange
yellow
green
blue
purple

Each of the columns has the amount of balls of that colour at the given time point. There are two rules:

the sum of the amounts is always 100
balls can't turn black after they are on, i.e. this number cannot increase

Should a simple LSTM model discover these rules all by itself? Is it possible (with a callback, maybe) to check for violation of the rules and to increase the loss manually?
